# How to append time stamps to storage file in Node-red?

Tags: node.js, node-red

I am using node-red *storage to file* feature to log some data to a file. I have been able to do so but I would like to include some time stamp to those entries in the file.

Is this possible within node-red itself? I haven't seen an specific option to add timestamps or so.

Thanks in advance,

Regards!

EDIT:

WHat I am doing in the end is appending the data in my json payload, which will be afterwards send to the file. The command that I use to set the date is

```
new Date (new Date().getTime()).toLocaleString({ timeZone: 'Europe/Berlin' })
```

Comment: What have you already tried? What sort of data is it, what format do you want the time stamp in? Your going to have to give us more info here

Comment: I would like to have just something like the year:day:hour:seconds appended in each entry in my file. What I am trying it's appending it to the message itself

Comment: Is the message payload json?

Comment: yes it is, I was playing with `Date().getTime()`

Comment: I am using that function, but I cannot make to work in my local area, it takes always UTM instead...

Comment: If it is a simple format problem, I'm  used to play with 'moment' library for my  date objects. Simple way to handle local and format. Hope it could help you...